# I have to POST JSON data to a page and redirect to that page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have 2 pages "page1" and "page2".

onclick of a button in page1, i have to access 5 input control values and send to page2.
Load page2 with some data based on those input values.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC the common scenario is posting data from page1 to your controller and then controller will redirect to page2 with updated data. You cannot post data directly between MVC views